# Function with a property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, properties

I have an object `parameter` and it has a property `value`. it is thusly defined

```
var parameter = {
    value : function() {
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

my problem is that, in some cases, value needs to have a property of its own named `length`

can i do that? it seems that putting `this.length = foo` does not work, neither does `parameter.value.length = foo` after the object declaration.

Comment: Do you mean that the returned object from `value()` needs to have a length?

Comment: no, i check `value`'s length and iterate over it as though it were an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the selection of the word 'length'.  In JavaScript, functions are objects and can have properties.  All functions already have a length property which returns the number of parameters the function is declared with.  This code works:

```
var parameter = {
    value : function() {
        //do stuff
    }
};

parameter.value.otherLength = 3;

alert(parameter.value.otherLength);
```

Comment: Ken is correct I believe (I was beaten to this answer)...see http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/ and http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#87

Comment: ok, well, that makes things interesting. the reason i picked length is because value is an array in most cases and i wanted the function to seem like an array in that sense. but thank you.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for that first link ken. I had a different issue that this addresses completely.

Comment: :D You might also try looking at how jQuery instantiates itself -- a jQuery object (the result of a jQuery _query_, such as `jQuery('*')`), uses a `length` property to emulate arrays. You have lots of options here, though!

Answer (score 2):

`parameter.value.length` *should* work. Run the following:

```
var obj = {
    method: function () {}
};
obj.method.foo = 'hello world';
alert(obj.method.foo); // alerts "hellow world"
```

Functions are technically objects, so they can have methods and properties of their own.

Comment: but not if i try to define length

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It should work:

```
var parameter = {
  value : {
    length : ''
  }
}

var newLength = parameter.value.length = 10;
alert( newLength ); // output: 10
```

If I understand your question, basically, in object literals notation, an object can contain another object and so on. So to access the inner object and its properties, you just have to do the dot natation as usual following the hierarchy. In the above case *'parameter'* then the inner-object, *'value'*, then the inner-object property, *'length'*.

Comment: My issue comes from defining `value` as a function.